# Is there a way to create instant messages using django?

Tags: python, django

So, I spent a few hours browsing through github repositories and through the internet for a possible way to create a messaging app using django But I can't seem to find any .. The only thing i could find was ways to create chatrooms but nothing about creating a one-to-one convos
Is it possible to do this in django at all?

Comment: isn't a one-to-one conversation just a chatroom for just 2 people?

Comment: You might want to take a look at Django Channels https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: @BrianH. Well yes but most of the ways that are used to create chatrooms require them to be set manually so users can't just create one

Answer (score 0):

a simple solution was to add a database to the django-channels and edit the consumer.py file

[Final Project Result](https://github.com/Raouf06/Django-ChatApp)

Hope it helps someone :)